# JQuery - How to change a variable value according to the section id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not so good with JQuery - and I have been crazy looking for a solution for a issue..

I have a script to animated icons on screen with a delay.

Its a generic script and Works for all sections of my page.

But I have some sections with 300 icons and other section with 10 icons.

If I choice a 1s delay for the section with 300 icons I need to wait 300s to complete.. (loooooong time) -

and If I change the delay to 8 ms the delay for this sections is perfect, but for the other section with only 10 icons is too fast (I can see the delay).

I have on the page a scroolspy system working - if it is important...

I need a way to identify the section and set the delay according the section id..

on my script I have this line:

```
const MULTIPLIER = 80; //ms
```

I need something like:

```
var currentSection = $(".nav li.active > a").attr('href');
if (currentSection === "#clients")  {
        const MULTIPLIER = 10; 

        } else {
        const MULTIPLIER = 800; 

        };
```

I dont know my current section, then my idea is discover the current section using the scrollspy of the nav menu.

Comment: I would suggest not using a constant for a value that can change...? It's entirely unclear what you want from us. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Divide the total desired delay by the number of icons to get the delay per icon.

Answer (score 0):

If the only criterion is the number of icons in a container, I would do this:

```
var delay = ($("#sectionID img").length === 10) ? 240 : 8; // since some sections have 10 and the other have 30 times this number or 240
```

Comment: Hi great idea! I will try this! tkssss

Comment: humm.. I try - but the problem is: I KNOW the number of icons - but I dont know the "sectionID"

Comment: On Chrome, right click on the container, and Inspect Element. Look for the parent of the icons. If this container has an ID, use this, else if you have access to the source code, place an ID on this element. If neither, you would need to use a more complex selector

Comment: BTW I assume your "icons" are actually <img> elements, right?

Comment: hi, no.. I'm using <i><img></i> for the client section (with 300 logos) and <i class="fa fa-expand fa-2x"></i> for the solutions section (with 10 fontawesome icons). The animation scripts looking for <i></i> to make the delay. I understand now your script -  If I have 10 icons the delay will be 240? or 240:8 (30ms)? And If I have more than 10?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the total time that you want the animation to take by the number of icons.

```
var delay = 2400 / $(currentSection).find(".icon").length;
```

When the number of icons is `300`, this will set `delay` to `8 ms`. When the number is only `10`, it will set it to `240 ms`. In both cases, the total delay will be `2.4 sec`.

Comment: tks a lot for you time! Great Idea.. I will try ! I'm only afraid because the script animate only the icons on viewport.  Maybe a fixed value for each section was a better solution..

Comment: Then count the number of icons in the viewport. The same idea works.

Comment: hum.. I test here (I'm a beginner with JS and Jquery) - It's Works, but to work I need to know the sectionid right? (I put var delay = 2400 / $("#SOLUTIONS").find(".icon").length) - Works for section solutions - but, of course, the delay will be same for every section. My problem is - I dont know the active section

Comment: Do you assign a class to the active section? Then use `$(".active")`

Comment: humm. I will try! But I think the solution is here: if ($(".nav li.active > a").attr('href')) === "#solutions"  {
        const MULTIPLIER = 10;

  } else {
  const MULTIPLIER = 800;

  };   I have a nav with scrollspy - then I think If I got the href of nav I can find where I am.. but for some reason with this the script brokes..